# Escanear códigos QR en IONIC 4?

Tags: ionic, ionic4

Buenas me gustaría saber si a día de hoy es posible realizar este proceso en IONIC 4, de entrada la documentación oficial no funciona, nose si habra algun plugin de la comunidad o algo, saludos. Aqui os dejo el código sacado de la documentacion oficial

```
    eventoCodigoQR(){

        this.qrScanner.prepare()
            .then((status: QRScannerStatus) =>
            {
                if (status.authorized)
                {
                    alert("permisos ganados");
                    // Comienzo el scaneo
                    let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) =>
                    {
                        alert("entra a scan!!!")
                        console.log('Scanned something', text);

                        this.qrScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
                        scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
                    });

                } else if (status.denied)
                {
                    // camera permission was permanently denied
                    // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
                    // then they can grant the permission from there
                } else
                {
                    // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
                }
            })
            .catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
    }
```

Comment: Yo he usado éste scanner en Angular (sin Ionic), debería funcionarte: https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner

Comment: Como se instala?

Comment: npm i @zxing/ngx-scanner

Comment: por que no funciona la documentacion oficial? cual es el error?